# ArrayStoreException in Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I am working with inheritance while i encounter such problem.
my code is as follows

```
   public class Parent {
        public void methodParent() {
            System.out.println("Parent");
        }
   }
   public class Child extends Parent {
    public void methodParent() {
        System.out.println("override method in Child");
    }

    public void methodChild() {
        System.out.println("method in Child");
    }
   }
   public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child[] c = new Child[10];
        Parent[] p = c;

        p[0] =  new Parent();
        c[0].methodParent();
    }
  }
```

stack trace is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: com.test.Parent
    at com.test.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:10)
```

when i debug 
inspect c then i got message like

```
org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.
```

please help me to understand where is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input,

I understand that ArrayStoreException
but now i just update my Parent class to interface
and child implement Parent
according to all of you code works fine

but when i debug inspect c then i got message like
`org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.`

please help why this error occurs at runtime and resolves automatically.

Comment: org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.

Why it gives me this error while debugging??
please explain!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this

```
    Child[] c = new Child[10];
    Parent[] p = c;
```

you are telling the compiler that `p` is just an array of Parent.  However, there is also a runtime check that the array still must contain `Child` references.  It is this runtime check which fails.

Answer (score 2):

See [`ArrayStoreException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong
>   type of object into an array of objects. For example, the following
>   code generates an ArrayStoreException:
>
> ```
>  Object x[] = new String[3];
>  x[0] = new Integer(0);
> ```

That's exactly what are you trying to do. And that's not right. You're getting the exception in the line:

```
p[0] =  new Parent();
```

Here, you are trying to assign to `p` an instance of `Parent`, although it must contain `Child` according to the assignment you did before.

It's **exactly** like the example shown in the official docs, `Parent` is `Object` and `Child` is `Integer`.

Comment: Oh my twin brother :)

Answer (score 1):

From docs

> Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects. For example, the following code generates an ArrayStoreException:

```
 Object x[] = new String[3];
 x[0] = new Integer(0);
```

This what exactly happend at  `Parent[] p = c;`

How ever you should consider using interfaces :)

Answer (score 1):

the actual type of the array which is assigned to variable 'p' is Child[]. Therefore this array can only 'store' instances of child objects. You are trying to store a parent to this array which is why the 'array store exception' is being thrown.

assigning a Child[] to a variable type of Parent[] is fine since child is a parent (as per your model). However the actual type of the array is checked at runtime by the jvm when it comes to storing objects inside the array.